# What is the priority between server.servlet.session.timeout and jdbcSessionRepository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-session

In my spring boot project, I find two ways to set the session timeout, the first is set the `server.servlet.session.timeout` in `application.properties`, and the another way is using `jdbcSessionRepository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval` in my java program. I find the min of them can work when real use, so my question is: What is the priority between them, or what is the difference of them.
Thank for your answers.

`server.servlet.session.timeout` and
`setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that `setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval` is part of the [Spring Session](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session) project, so it can only be used if you include Spring Session in your project.

`server.servlet.session.timeout` can be used in a servlet based application, regardless of whether you include Spring Session.

If you set both, the value in `setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval` takes precedence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but when i both set server.servlet.session.timeout=1m and setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(PT1H) ,i find the session timed out after one minute,so i guess the application take the min of them,is it right?

Comment: @周嘉晔 I wouldn't expect that behaviour. I expect `setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval` to take precedence. If you want to open a new question and share how you are setting `setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval` I can take a look.